# Preferences attributes doesn't work properly

Tags: android-preferences

I'm trying to read the attributes from the preference file in the way shown below:

```
boolean status = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(PREFERECES_NS, ATTR_DEFAULT_VALUE, false)
```

I can't figure it out why status variable is always false, regardless of the value assigned to the attribute in preferences file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this problem using getAttributeBooleanValue() method. However the workaround for this problem is:

```
attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.yourFullPackageName_ClassName);

status = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.yourFullPackageName_ClassName_YourAttributeNameFromPreferencesFile, false);
```